# Android studio saving radiogroup value when moving to new activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save the selected `RadioButton` value in this `RadioGroup` it gets saved in the `Activity` i am using but when i move to the next `Activity` and come back to `Activity` which had the selected `RadioButton` ... it goes back to be not selected . this is not happening only with the `RadioButton` i am using ... but with the text fields values too

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: post your startActivity code